# python inheritance - referencing base class methods

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
# Derived class that inherits from Base class. Only one of the 
# parent methods should be redefined. The other should be accessible
# by calling child_obj.parent_method().
class Derived(Base):
    def result(self,str):
        print "Derived String (result): %s" % str

# Base class that has two print methods
class Base():
    def result(self,str):
        print "Base String (result): %s" % str

    def info(self,str):
        print "Base String (info): %s" % str
```

I think what I want to do is simple, but I've never dealt with inheritance in Python. Nothing I'm trying seems to work. What I want to do is create a class that redefines a handful of the original methods in the base class while still being able to access all of the other methods in the base class. In the above example, I would want to be able to do this:

```
derived_obj.result("test")
derived_obj.info("test2")
```

And the output would be this:

```
Derived String (result): test
Base String (info): test2
```

Am I missing something or should this work as it's currently written?

Comment: It should work as you've written it down (provided you define `Base()` first). What problems do you see exactly?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure how to instantiate the objects. I've been reading enough to know how to define the classes, but I can't figure out the next step.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it'll work (almost) as-is:

```
class Base(object):

    def result(self, s):
        print "Base String (result): %s" % s

    def info(self, s):
        print "Base String (info): %s" % s

class Derived(Base):

    def result(self, s):
        print "Derived String (result): %s" % s

derived_obj = Derived()
derived_obj.result("test")
derived_obj.info("test2")
```

I have:

1. derived `Base` from `object`;
2. moved `Base` to appear before `Derived`;
3. renamed `str` since it's bad form to shadow [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html);
4. added code to instantiate `Derived`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I see what Martijn meant in his comment on my original post now. Also, thanks for the tip in number 3.